# Is a regression model the best model to use for predicting stock prices based on other stocks considering the multicollinearity problem?

Tags: regression, forecasting, multicollinearity, finance

I'm just learning how to use Sklearn and python for data analysis.  One of the projects I'm working on is trying to predict the price of a stock over a short time span (a few minutes) based on the moves of other similar stocks.  I used a regression model and the initial results look really good (r squared at 0.99 and very low RMSE and MAE).

My question is about the multicollinearity problem since the correlation is incredibly high between the "independent" variables (0.9 or higher).  My concern is that if you remove highly correlated variables, there won't be any left since they are all highly correlated.

Is a regression model the best model to use or is there another predictive model that will solve the multicollinearity problem?  Or, given the nature of the data, is multicollinearity even a problem in this case since there really doesn't seem like any other option?

Comment: Is it possible you have data leakage? I.e., is it possible you are using information from the future to predict events that happened in the past? If so, this is a much more severe problem for prediction than any possible multi-collinearity.

Comment: Also, multicollinearity is usually not considered much of a concern in prediction (it does not really harm it), unlike inference.